# Overwrite styles depends on root class

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I've a question how to overwrite styles depends on main class using scss.
For an example we have a component

app.component.html

```
<div [ngClass]="variable === 'mobile' ? 'container-fluid user' : 'container'"> 
  <child-component></app-components>
</div>
```

child-component.html

```
<h1 class="custom-heading">Test</h1>
...
<button class="main-btn"> Test </button>
```

So the case is overwrite classes custom-heading and main-btn when the root component div has class user.

I want to change all elements styles depends on variable name.

Comment: I'm not clear - do you want to set different styling if the root component div has class user or do you want to set different styling depending on a (CSS?) variable.

Comment: @AHaworth, If the main div has class user i want to overwrite existing class styles to another.
e.g 
Existing: .main-btn { 
height: 40px
}

overwrite to main-btn {
height: 60px 
}

Comment: So something like .user .custom-heading { different styling here }?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, but it's need to work globally for whole project

Comment: You have to disable styles encapsulation in angular: `ViewEncapsulation.None` or pass that data via inputs to the components

Answer (score 0):

Need use `:host-context` in child style file.

Example(scss):

```
:host-context(.parent-class) {
 .custom-heading { ...some styles }
 .main-btn { ...some styles }
}
```